# Chi-Squared test for independence with one data column as integer and other as object?

Tags: python, pandas, chi-squared, hypothesis-test, statistical-test

I'm trying to perform hypothesis test for Independence in python but my one data column(finances) has float data type and other column(gender) has object data type.

I have created the following hypothesis:
Ho : finances are gender independent
Ha : finances are gender dependent

I tried directly using the inputs but I'm getting the following error:
" could not convert string to float: 'female' "

```py
import pandas      as pd
import numpy       as np
import scipy.stats as stats

test = np.array(df['Gender'],df['Finances'])
chi_sq_Stat, p_value, deg_freedom, exp_freq = stats.chi2_contingency(test)

print('Chi-square statistic %3.5f P value %1.6f Degrees of freedom %d' %(chi_sq_Stat, p_value,deg_freedom))
```

I'm expecting some P value to verify my hypothesis.

I have attached an image of data set

[image: dataset]

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping the gender which is a nominal variable into a fixed set of numbers like this:

```
gender_mapping = {"male":1 ,"female":0}
df.Gender = df.Gender.map(gender_mapping)
df.head()
Gender  Finances
0   1   1
1   0   2
2   1   3
3   0   2
4   1   3
```